# How do I uses AWS SecureTokenService with Spring Cloud AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud

I need to use AWS Secure Token Service(sts) as per my company's guidelines. I don't see anything in the spring cloud aws documentation for using sts tokens.

Can someone provide any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

if you put the following in config:

```
<aws-context:context-credentials>
    <aws-context:instance-profile-credentials/>
</aws-context:context-credentials>
```

you will use the creds from the EC2 Instance metadata. Those credentials are already rotated and using STS so there is nothing else you need to do.

Further reference (trace the option from doc to github to actual bean that is used):
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/ -> 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws  -> 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/context/config/xml/ContextCredentialsBeanDefinitionParser.java#L46   -> 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.html

Comment: Thanks!! I will give it a try. I was trying to use a s3 service (using spring cloud aws extension of the resourceloader). So I am not using EC2. Does that make a difference?

Comment: to understand this correctly: the service is not running on an EC2 instance? STS and instance metadata as described above need to be run on an EC2 instance. there may be a way to use STS outside of that but it's probably not going to work out of the box

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I am trying to write a program that runs on-premises but connects to s3 using spring Cloud AWS Resource Loader. I am able to run it fine using the AWS s3 APIs directly. I use the aws cli to generate the secure token service's access key, secret key and session token. As long as those are in the credentials file, I am able to access the AWS s3 APIs directly. Was wondering if I needed to do anything different to use Spring Cloud AWS.

Comment: I was able to get this working using the aws cli to generate a config file that contained the necessary access keys as well as session token.

Comment: @AshvinIyengar can you please give the steps how you got it to work

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure your temporary credentials are valid, run `aws2 s3 ls`. If not valid, refresh it by `aws2 sso login`
2. Copy the temporary credentials from `~/.aws/cli/cache/*.json` to `~/.aws/credentials` file. Note use `default` profile for you credentials meaning your `~/.aws/credentials` should have content in format

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=""
aws_secret_access_key=""
aws_session_token=""
```

(You can use open source project also for step 1 and 2 -
https://github.com/arvindkgs/aws_sso_login)

3. Setting my application.yaml with

   cloud.aws.credentials.useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain: true

This will cause aws-sdk-java to pick up temporary credentials from `~/.aws/credentials`

- You can also use environment variables as given in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html
- For more details on spring configuration for aws check https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__basic_setup.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration